# SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory' when trying to run the first update-database command in WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to apply the intiial migration on my database, I have this error SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.

I want to specify that the command add-migration Initial works fine and creates the migration but when I want to apply it I get that error.

I will attach down below the creation of ApplicationDbContext.

```
namespace ToDoListApp.Data;
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TasksConfiguration());
    }
}
```

```
namespace ToDoListApp.Data;
public class ApplicationDesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];

    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlite(_connectionString).Options;

        return new ApplicationDbContext(options);
    }
}
```

```
public class TasksConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Task>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Task> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        builder.Property(t => t.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(35)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

```
namespace ToDoListApp;
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private string _connectionString = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];

    public App()
    {
        ConfigureServices();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<TaskWindow>();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(_connectionString));
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<Task>, TaskRepositoryDatabase>();
        services.AddScoped<IService<Task>, TaskService>();
        services.AddScoped<TaskViewModel>();

        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var taskWindow = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TaskWindow>();
        taskWindow.DataContext = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TaskViewModel>();

        taskWindow.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I found online but nothing worked. That's why I'm writing this now.

Comment: *I want to specify that the command add-migration Initial works fine and creates the migration but when I want to apply it I get that error.*
 So the package manager console command works fine for you?  it adds a migration folder to your project, is that it?  And when you then start up and create the `DbContext` object you call its `Migrate()` function?  Is that what's failing?

Comment: Yes, it adds the migration folder to the project. But when I use the command "update-database" in the packet manager console I get the SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'

Comment: If you've just created the database with `add-migration` you should not need to call update-database.  Just make sure that when your app starts you call `Migrate()` on the `DbContext`.

Comment: There is a Visual Studio extension you can get called "SQLite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox".  If you get it and install it, it gives you a little explorer window where you can open up your SQLite database and look at the tables.  When I look at mine, I see the __EFMigrationsHistory table  But I have applied multiple migrations to mine so I would expect to have a history.  I don't think a brand new DB would have one (I haven't verified)